# Nodejs app crash on kerberos when npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying build one npm app, but i always get this error:

```
Step 14/17 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in be1741689869
> kerberos@0.0.24 install /usr/src/app/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/app/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:189:0,
                 from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:203,
                 from ../lib/kerberos.h:9,
                 from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function 'static Nan::imp::FactoryBase<v8::StringObject>::return_t Nan::imp::Factory<v8::StringObject>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>)':
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:37: warning: 'static v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::StringObject::New(v8::Local<v8::String>)' is deprecated: Use Isolate* version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                     ^
In file included from /root/.node-gyp/11.15.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /root/.node-gyp/11.15.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../lib/kerberos.h:4,
                 from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/11.15.0/include/node/v8.h:5242:37: note: declared here
```

And many others similar lines, like really many that i cant paste all here.. i really dont know what to do, can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using windows or ubuntu or what as OS ? it has specific requirement before installation using npm

Comment: this is from ubuntu, on windows it seems it built sucessfuly

Comment: Requirements for Linux
python v2.7
make
A proper C/C++ compiler toolchain, like GCC
Distribution-specific kerberos packages (e.g. krb5-dev on Ubuntu)

Comment: I have all :( RUN apt-get install -y python
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y manpages-dev
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y g++